# sql server 2008 math converion

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to convert 539.9000 to .5399 using SQL Server 2008. How ?

Comment: I'm making some assumptions here, but would this work? `UPDATE table SET column = column/1000`

Comment: I think I have to mark this as a close for being too specific, I mean what are the chances of someone else needing to divide 539.9000 by 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just divide it by 1000.

SELECT 539.9000 / 1000

Comment: I was so thrown by how fundamental this question is that I had to go and test the answer I had and then NKCSS beat me to the post ;) Nice +1

Comment: Thank you for the compliment :)